# New SSD and how restore backup on it

Tags: macos, time-machine, ssd, restore

iMac 2009 HDD failed so I installed a new SSD. I have a TM backup on an external drive, but now I can't figure out how to get the system up and running. I tried <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the recovery mode but I get alternating Apple logo and round circle with a diagonal line through it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect the TM Backup drive to your mac and hold the <kbd>alt/opt</kbd> key when booting. You should be able to see your time machine drive and boot from it. Once booted you can restore the time machine backup to your new SSD.

Comment: Thanks, but if I remember correctly, I tried that and it didn't work. I ended up downloading a bootable something (drive, maybe?) onto an external HD (wow, what a pain with partitioning, etc). I then had to format the new SSD (don't remember how I even did that). Then I put the OS on the new HD and went from there. Whew...what a complete pain. It has taken me 4 hours so far